# Consumer_failed_message in kafka stream: Records not pushed from topic

Tags: ksqldb, confluent-platform, kafka-topic

I have a flow where from IBM mainframe IIDR, I am sending records to Kafka topic. The `value_format` of the message coming to Kafka topic is AVRO and the key is in AVRO format too. The records are pushed into the Kafka topic. I have a stream associated with that topic. But the records are not passed into the stream.
Example of the `test_iidr` topic -

```
rowtime: 5/30/20 7:06:34 PM UTC, key: {"col1": "A", "col2": 1}, value: {"col1": "A", "col2": 11, "col3": 2, "iidr_tran_type": "QQ", "iidr_a_ccid": "0", "iidr_a_user": " ", "iidr_src_upd_ts": "2020-05-30 07:06:33.262931000", "iidr_a_member": " "}
```

The value_format in the stream is AVRO and the column names are all checked.

The stream creation query -

```sql
CREATE STREAM test_iidr (
  col1 STRING, 
  col2 DECIMAL(2,0),
  col3 DECIMAL(1,0),
  iidr_tran_type STRING,
  iidr_a_ccid STRING,
  iidr_a_user STRING,
  iidr_src_upd_ts STRING,
  iidr_a_member STRING) 
WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='test_iidr', PARTITIONS=1, REPLICAS=3, VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');
```

Is it failing to load into the stream from the topic as the `KEY` is not mentioned in `WITH` statement?
The schema registry has the `test_iidr-value` and `test_iidr-key` subjects registered in it.

The `key.converter` and `value.converter` in the `Kafka-connect` docker is set as - `org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter`. Is this `JsonConverter` creating this issue?

I created a completely different pipeline with different stream and inserted the same data manually using `insert into` statements. It worked. Only the IIDR flow is not working and the records are not pushed into the stream from the topic.

I am using Confluent kafka version 5.5.0.

Comment: the issue is resolved. Looks like there was de-serialization error because of DECIMAL and INT. The source was sending INT values and we had DECIMAL as the datatype for those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JsonConverter` in the connect config could well be converting your Avro data to JSON.

To determine the key and value serialization formats you can use the `PRINT` command, (which I can see you've already run).  `PRINT` will output the key and value formats when it runs. For example:

```
ksql> PRINT some_topic FROM BEGINNING LIMIT 1;
Key format: JSON or KAFKA_STRING
Value format: JSON or KAFKA_STRING
rowtime: 5/30/20 7:06:34 PM UTC, key: {"col1": "A", "col2": 1}, value: {"col1": "A", "col2": 11, "col3": 2, "iidr_tran_type": "QQ", "iidr_a_ccid": "0", "iidr_a_user": " ", "iidr_src_upd_ts": "2020-05-30 07:06:33.262931000", "iidr_a_member": " "}
```

So the first thing to check is the formats output for the key and value by PRINT and then update your `CREATE` statement accordingly.

Note, ksqlDB does not *yet* support Avro/Json keys, so you may want/need to repartition your data, see: https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/syntax-reference/#what-to-do-if-your-key-is-not-set-or-is-in-a-different-format

**Side note**: If the schema for the value is stored in the Schema Registry, then you don't need to define the columns in your CREATE statement as ksqlDB will load the columns from the Schema Registry

**Side note**: you don't need `PARTITIONS=1, REPLICAS=3` in the `WITH` clause for existing topics, only if you want ksqlDB to create the topic for you.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I made the changes. The problem was with the data type DECIMAL. the source was sending as INTEGER instead of DECIMAL and the Kafka stream had DECIMAL in the schema. We updated that to INT. It worked

Comment: Great stuff. Glad you got it working. Can you mark the question as answered please?